# Required request body is missing exception from Vue to Spring

Tags: spring, vue.js, axios, request

I'm trying to send data from Vue to Spring

I've been searching everywhere and everything looks perfect but still it doesn't work

At first I was thinking may be because my class in back have more fields than what I send from front but even though I created another class with same fields it doesn't work

Here is my send request:

```
sendRequest() {
  console.log(this.user);
  (this.loading = true),
    axios.get("http://localhost:8081/user/log-in", this.user)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        (this.isShow = true),
          (this.isHide = false),
          (this.showAlert = true),
          (this.message = error.response.data);
        (this.showMessage = true),
          setTimeout(
            function () {
              this.showMessage = false;
              (this.isShow = false), (this.isHide = true);
            }.bind(this),
            3000
          );
      })
      .finally(() => {
        this.loading = false;
      });
```

Here data I send from front to back:

```
      user: {
    userName: "",
    password: ""
  },
```

Here my back end class that get data:

```
public class UserSignUpDTO {

private String firstName;

private String userName;

private String email;

private String password;

private String birthDay;

}
```

And here is the method that get data:

```
    @GetMapping("/log-in")
public UserDTO logInUser(@RequestBody UserSignUpDTO user) throws Exception {
    return userService.logInUser(user);
}
```

Mapping for request:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It is not advisable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/978094/5183029) to use a GET with a request body. While [HTTP/1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) does not seem to explicitly forbid this, it should not have meaning.

As hinted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/983458/5183029),

> If you give it meaning by parsing it on the server and changing your response based on its contents, then you are ignoring this recommendation in the HTTP/1.1 spec, section 4.3.

I would advise you use a POST request in this case.

**Change this**

```
axios.get("http://localhost:8081/user/log-in", this.user)
```

**To this**

```
axios.post("http://localhost:8081/user/log-in", this.user)
```